# LISP function for building a binary search tree is not working and I don't understand why

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun leftorright (element tree)
  (cond ((null (car tree))
         (setf tree
               (cons element (cons (cons NIL NIL) (cons NIL  NIL)))))
        ((>= element (car tree))
         (if (null (caddr tree))
             (setf (cddr tree)
                   (cons element (cons (cons NIL NIL) (cons NIL NIL))))
            (leftorright element (cddr tree))))
        ((< element (car tree))
         (if (null (caaddr tree))
             (setf (cadr tree)
                   (cons element (cons (cons NIL NIL) (cons NIL NIL))))
             (leftorright element (cadr tree))))))

(setf tree (cons NIL NIL))
(print tree)
(leftorright 8 tree)
(leftorright 3 tree)
(leftorright 6 tree)
(leftorright 4 tree)
(leftorright 7 tree)
(print tree)
```

Comment: the formatting of the code makes it unreadable. Try again.

Comment: `(setf tree ...)` mutates local binding. It never alters the passed object like `(setf (cddr tree) ..)` does.

Comment: You cannot just paste code into a StackOverflow answer as if it were another paragraph. There are markup conventions to follow. Either you indent the code block by four spaces (every line of it), or else put `\`\`\`` (three backticks on their own line) before and after the code.

Comment: What Sylwester means is that your `(setf tree ...)` in the function has no effect. The value of the variable `tree` is changed, but nothing uses it after that point in the function, so the change has no meaning. `tree` is a local variable which disappears when the function terminates.

Comment: However, `(setf x y)` returns the same value `y` that is assigned to `x`. So if the last form of the function that is evaluated is `(setf tree (whatever))`, then that is the same thing as just writing `(whatever)`. Either way, the `(whatever)` value gets returned.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun leftorright (element tree)
  (cond ((null (car tree))
         (setf tree
               (cons element (cons (cons NIL NIL) (cons NIL  NIL)))))
        ((>= element (car tree))
         (if (null (caddr tree))
             (setf (cddr tree)
                   (cons element (cons (cons NIL NIL) (cons NIL NIL))))
            (leftorright element (cddr tree))))
        ((< element (car tree))
         (if (null (caaddr tree))
             (setf (cadr tree)
                   (cons element (cons (cons NIL NIL) (cons NIL NIL))))
             (leftorright element (cadr tree))))))
```

So looking at

```
(setf tree (cons NIL NIL))
(print tree)
```

You think of the tree structure as something with 2 slots - a left and a right one. `leftorright` is actually an `inser` function which takes an element and fits the element into either left or right slot of a tree.

`(null (car tree))` considers the case that the tree is empty.
In that case you want to set `tree`
`(cons element (cons (cons NIL NIL) (cons NIL  NIL)))`.
Let's take `'element` as value for `element` just to see the returned structure:
`(ELEMENT (NIL) NIL)`
Here is already some problem. Why not `(element nil nil)`? OR: `(element (nil) (nil))`?
In the next `cond` clauses, you distinguish between the cases that `element` is `>=` `(car tree)` (the current value?) and `<` than `(car tree)`.
Then, in the next step you distinguish the case that the first subtree `(caddr tree)` is `null` - thus empty. In that case you again build `(element (nil) nil)`. But you assign it to some subparts of tree.
`(caddr tree)` or `(cadr tree)`. If they are not empty you delegate to `leftorright` to handle those subtreeparts.

So as many commentators point our, your `(setf tree ...)` expressions are problematic - because they are mutating `tree` -
obviously you come from some non-lisp language (which we lispers call `blubb` language) and try to think in the `blubb` way - meaning imperatively.

The lisp-way for such tree functions is always to recursively construct a tree and return the entire tree.

Recursion means to break down the cases into the very primitive and simple cases - and just to think-through one step.

So what is the most primitive case of `tree`? - If we assume that it is actually a list - probably of the length 3 `(current-value left right)`.

The most primitive tree is the empty tree. `(null tree)`.

So we start with

```
(defun insert (element tree)
  (cond ((null tree) (cons element (cons nil (cons nil nil))))
        ...))
```

However, cons cons cons is not as nice as once a `list`. So let's do:

```
(defun insert (element tree)
  (cond ((null tree) (list element nil nil))
         ...))
```

And we use `list` for constructing a tree.

If the tree is not empty, it contains 3 slots - the first for the element (current-value) and the seconds and third slots are for sub-trees (either an empty-tree - '() - or another 3-slot-list - a real tree.

For the next element which gets inserted to any non-empty tree - the criterion is the current value. Any element >= than the current value gets inserted as a tree into the right slot. Otherwise/else/`<` into the left slot.

```
(defun insert (element tree)
  (cond ((null tree)
         (list element
               nil
               nil))
        ((>= element (car tree))
         (list (car tree) (cadr tree) (insert element (caddr tree))))
        (t
         (list (car tree) (insert element (cadr tree)) (caddr tree)))))
```

and that is actually what you wanted.
Let's use it:

```
(defparameter *tree* nil) ;; generate an empty tree
```

Now let's insert - but now we assign the result anew to `*tree*` using `setf`.

```
(setf *tree* (insert 8 *tree*))
(setf *tree* (insert 3 *tree*))
(setf *tree* (insert 6 *tree*))
(setf *tree* (insert 4 *tree*))
(setf *tree* (insert 7 *tree*))

;; let's see how now *tree* looks like:
*tree*
;; => (8 (3 NIL (6 (4 NIL NIL) (7 NIL NIL))) NIL)
```

### Let's improve the function

We are lazy, we don't want to write so often `setf` and we want to give in order the numbers to be inserted.

First, we change the order of the arguments:

```
(defun insert (tree element)
  (cond ((null tree)
         (list element
               nil
               nil))
        ((>= element (car tree))
         (list (car tree) (cadr tree) (insert (caddr tree) element)))
        (t
         (list (car tree) (insert (cadr tree) element) (caddr tree)))))
```

And then, we make this function variadic - means it can take as many arguments as we want (namely the sequence of the elements):

```
(defun insert* (tree &rest elements)
  (let ((tree tree))
    (loop for e in elements
          do (setf tree (insert tree e))
          finally (return tree))))
```

Now we can do:

```
(insert* '() 8 3 6 4 7)
;;=> (8 (3 NIL (6 (4 NIL NIL) (7 NIL NIL))) NIL)
```

The nice thing is, we used a local `(let ((tree tree)) ...)`
and we loop over the elements and do `(setf tree ...)` meaning we mutate the local tree only. So the global variable given for tree is unaffected.
Unless we `setf` the new result to the global tree's variable.
Like this:

```
(defparameter *tree* '())
(setf *tree* (insert* *tree* 8 3 6 4 7))
*tree*
;;=> (8 (3 NIL (6 (4 NIL NIL) (7 NIL NIL))) NIL)
```

`setf` is necessary to change the `*tree*` value.
Look:

```
(defparameter *tree* '())
(insert* *tree* 8 3 6 4 7)
*tree*
;;=> NIL  ;; original *tree* value is not altered by `insert*` function!
```

### Destructive `insert!`

I also tried a destructive `insert!`.
However, perhaps things could be improved. I am open for suggestions.

```
(defun %insert! (tree element &optional (acc '()))
  "Generate setf expression for `insert!` macro!"
  (cond ((null tree)
         (nreverse (cons (list element nil nil) acc)))
        ((>= element (car tree))
         (%insert! (third tree) element (cons 'third acc)))
        (t
         (%insert! (second tree) element (cons 'second acc)))))

(defun butlast-last (l &optional (acc '()))
  (cond ((or (null l) (null (cdr l))) (values (nreverse acc) (car l)))
        (t (butlast-last (cdr l) (cons (car l) acc)))))

(defun %insert!-to-setf (%insert!-expression tree)
  (multiple-value-bind (seq expr) (butlast-last %insert!-expression)
    (append (cons 'setf (list (reduce (lambda (res e) (cons e (list res))) seq :initial-value tree)))
            (list (cons 'quote (list expr))))))

(defmacro insert! (tree element)
  (eval `(%insert!-to-setf (%insert! ,tree ,element) ',tree)))
```

The usage of `eval` in the macro already signals something is very bad in this code.
See the last section of this answer to see how a better `insert!` and `insert*!` can be written!

### Destructive `insert!` and `insert*!` as pure functions

Finally, I figured out how to do destructive `insert!` and `insert*!` as pure functions.

```
(defun insert! (tree element)
  (let ((e (list element nil nil)))
    (cond ((null tree)
           (setf tree e))
          (t
           (labels ((%insert! (itree)
                      (cond ((>= element (first itree))
                             (if (null (third itree))
                                 (setf (third itree) e)
                                 (%insert! (third itree))))
                            (t
                             (if (null (second itree))
                                 (setf (second itree) e)
                                 (%insert! (second itree)))))))
             (%insert! tree))))
    tree))

(defun insert*! (tree &rest elements)
  (loop for e in elements
        do (setf tree (insert! tree e))
        finally (return tree)))



(defparameter *t* '())
(setf *t* (insert! *t* 3))
(setf *t* (insert! *t* 8))
(setf *t* (insert! *t* 7))
(setf *t* (insert! *t* 5))

(insert*! '() 3 8 7 5)
```

### And finally make out of them imperative macros

Imperative in that way that they are mutating the tree argument.
And you don't need to assign the results to a new value.
I think these macros are what you actually wanted to program!
BUT destructive `insert!` and `insert*!` as pure functions is more lispier than the macros which are following now.

```
(defun %insert! (tree element)
  (let ((e (list element nil nil)))
    (cond ((null tree)
           (setf tree e))
          (t
           (labels ((%%insert! (itree)
                      (cond ((>= element (first itree))
                             (if (null (third itree))
                                 (setf (third itree) e)
                                 (%%insert! (third itree))))
                            (t
                             (if (null (second itree))
                                 (setf (second itree) e)
                                 (%%insert! (second itree)))))))
             (%%insert! tree))))
    tree))

(defun %insert*! (tree &rest elements)
  (loop for e in elements
        do (setf tree (%insert! tree e))
        finally (return tree)))

(defmacro insert! (tree element)
  `(setf ,tree (%insert! ,tree ,element)))

(defmacro insert*! (tree &rest elements)
  `(setf ,tree (%insert*! ,tree ,@elements)))



(defparameter *t* '())
(insert! *t* 3)
(insert! *t* 8)
(insert! *t* 7)
(insert! *t* 5)

(defparameter *t* '())
(insert*! *t* 3 8 7 5)
```

Comment: "So as many commentators point our, your (setf tree ...) expressions are problematic - because they are mutating tree - obviously you come from some non-lisp language (which we lispers call blubb language) and try to think in the blubb way - meaning imperatively." Oddly, the same applies to the reverse, trying to code Haskell in the style of Lisp. Because of  how Haskell handles laziness, using tail recursion is a bad idea.

Comment: @FrancisKing sure, Common Lisp, Haskell, Clojure each of them would have their peculirarities. - But hwy is tail recursion a bad idea with Haskell - what is the alternative?

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim the preferred alternative there is "guarded recursion", where a recursive call is "guarded by" i.e. sits behind a lazy data constructor. this achieves the effect of "tail recursion modulo cons".

Comment: @WillNess thanks for pointing that out - what you mean exactly by that?

Comment: @WillNess I googled it - thank you!

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim you're welcome. I should've said, "sits behind a lazy data constructor such as e.g. *`lazy-cons`*". In SICP e.g. they define lazy streams where `cons` is strict in its first argument, and lazy in its second argument, so definitions like `(define ones (stream-cons 1 ones))` become possible -- because it is translated as a plain Scheme `(define ones (cons 1 (lambda () ones)))` *approximately*, which instead of `car` and `cdr` would be accessed by `car` and `(lambda (x) ((cdr x)))`. In Scheme there are also [SRFI-40](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-40/srfi-40.html) and SRFI-41.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim also, https://www.google.com/search?q=why+is+tail+recursion+a+bad+idea+with+Haskell, and https://www.google.com/search?q=tail+recursion+modulo+cons and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tailrecursion-modulo-cons/info. :)